# Is there a better way to do this? BufferedImage related

Tags: java, bitmap, bufferedimage

I have a method in my project that runs only if both of the following conditions are true: the user presses the E key, and a pixel in the player's immediate vicinity is red on the unseen bitmap. The bitmap governs collision in my game. Here is the method:

```
private void doors(int x, int y) {
        int doorColor = 0xFFFF0000;
        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;
        while (bitmap.getRGB(x - 1, y) == doorColor)
            x--;
        while (bitmap.getRGB(x, y - 1) == doorColor)
            y--;
        while (bitmap.getRGB(x + w + 1, y) == doorColor)
            w++;
        while (bitmap.getRGB(x, y + h + 1) == doorColor)
            h++;
        for (int x2 = x; x2 < x + w + 1; x2++) {
            for (int y2 = y; y2 < y + h + 1; y2++) {
                foreground.setRGB(x2, y2, 0x00FFFFFF);
                bitmap.setRGB(x2, y2, 0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method, when given the x and y coordinates of the found red pixel, finds the top left corner of the red rectangle on the bitmap, and then finds the width and height of said rectangle. Once it has done this, it changes the colors of all the pixels in the rectangle to white, and clears the section of the foreground image to give the appearance of an opened door.

***This method of opening the door works, but it takes long enough that the game visibly freezes for a few frames. Is there any way to avoid this?***

### Here is my bitmap: [image]

### And here is my foreground image: [image]

Comment: Recommend re-writing your game using OpenGL ES

Comment: ^ What this guy said ^ Every game should use Opengl or DirectX. Period.

Comment: Rather then looping up pixels in a bitmap, you should be working with a virtual concept of your game/world, which is then translated to a graphical representation, it will generally be faster.  Since both Swing and JavaFX use either DirectX or OpenGL (depending on the platform and configuration), then you should be good to go ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you explain this in a practical way?

Comment: @Krythic I started to check out JOGL, then nearly had a stroke when i found out how difficult it is to just load an image and display it. Any alternatives?

Comment: Define a virtual concept of your world, maybe using Rectangle or other shapes, maybe using a 2D array, this is what you logic interacts with, then your graphics engine generates a physical representation of this model as it sees fit

Comment: There is no alternative. Take the dive. Learn Lwjgl if you want to stay with Java. You won't regret it.

Comment: @Krythic Alright. Will do.